# Vaadin and Spring integration: what replaces @VaadinServletConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

In my pre-spring code I had following configuration:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = AppUI.class, closeIdleSessions = true)
public class AppServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

But the [Book of Vaadin says in 11.18.9. Deploying Spring UIs and Servlets:
Custom Servlets](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.spring.html#advanced.spring.deployment)

> When customizing the Vaadin servlet, as outlined in Section 4.8.2, “Vaadin Servlet, Portlet, and Service”, you simply need to extend
>   com.vaadin.spring.internal.VaadinSpringServlet instead of
>   com.vaadin.servlet.VaadinServlet.
>
> ```
> @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
> public class MySpringServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
> }
> ```
>
> The custom servlet must not have @VaadinServletConfiguration, as you would normally with a Vaadin servlet, as described in Section 4.9,
>   “Deploying an Application”.

My question is: Where do I pass parameters from @VaadinServletConfiguration?

Answer (score 4):

You can define those in the `application.properties` file. For example:

```
vaadin.servlet.production-mode=true
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 and I am able to autocomplete those settings.

Answer (score 1):

This annotation just add init params to your vaadin servlet.

You ca override method, and add all manual

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class WebServletVaadinConfiguration extends VaadinServlet {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
      servletConfig.getServletContext().setInitParameter("productionMode","true");
     super.init(servletConfig);}
}
```